Solving a plate motion equation using variable separation and orthogonal eigenfunctions
Dear Math Stackexchange community,
Consider the following equation representing the time-dependent deflection, in $z$-direction, of a circular plate in cylindrical coordinates $(r,\phi,z)$
$$
\nabla^2 (\nabla^2 w(r,\phi,t)) + \frac{\rho t}{D} \frac{\partial^2 w(r,\phi,t)}{\partial t^2 }=q(r,\phi,t)
$$
where $w$ is the deflection, $\rho$ the plate density, $t$ the plate thickness, $D$ the bending stiffness, and $q$ the load on the plate. The plate is at rest at time $t=0$, and its boundary conditions are assumed to correspond to a "clamped" plate.
There are numerous examples in literature of how the equation can be solved, most often using separation of variables, followed by a mode summation technique (summation over infinite number of orthogonal eigenfunctions satisfying the boundary conditions). However, all these examples use simple, clearly separable, loads. The load I want to consider is non-separable with respect to $r$ and $t$ (but independent of $\phi$). Can the same solution method, as described above, be used for this type of non-separable load as well? Or should a different solution approach be used instead?

You can still use an eigenfunction expansion. The only tricky bit will be that you have to integrate $q$ against each eigenfunction $w_{mn}(r,\phi) = R_m(r)\Phi_n(\phi)$ jointly over $r,\phi$ instead of one variable at at time.

@whpowell96, thank you for your comment! I will give it a try.
